# Can a python script run a second python script independently while sharing data?

Tags: python, eclipse, pandas

I wonder if anyone would guide me with the right direction to create a code which performs these operations:

- The first code imports a series of libraries, performs a some of operations and generates some data (for example a pandas data frame)

  - The first code runs a second python script using as an argument this pandas dataframe array

-The second code imports a library and performs some operations independently of the objects and variables created by the first program

-The second program generates some data (a second data frame for example) and it stops

-The first program reads these data and works with it before closing

The question is then: how do you make a python script running a second script separately but transferring complex objects between then?

A bit of context :

I am using pyraf which is a python based library which works  over IRAF.  The latter is a very important astronomical library but with a very...  Conflicting design...  For example: If I run matplotlib before this a pyraf object I get crushes.  Moreover,  I work with eclipse and if I run a pyraf routine I also get errors.  So I need to run the second script as if it were from the terminal independent of where the actual first code is actually working. I understand I can generate files which preserve the data from one code to another but I wonder if there is a cleaner approach

Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172213/making-two-scripts-communicate)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation it I s very interesting discussion.  If you post it as an answer I can set it as the solution